# how to get column names from postgres table using python psycopg2?

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

I am trying to get column names from my postgres sql table using psycopg2 but it is returning unordered column list not same as how columns are shown in table.

**This is how database table look when saved as pandas dataframe:**

```
cur.execute("Select * from actor")
tupples = cur.fetchall()

cur.execute("select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'actor'")
column_name = cur.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(tupples,columns = column_name)
```

```
  (actor_id,)  (last_update,)  (first_name,)  (last_name,)

    1   PENELOPE    GUINESS     2006-02-15 04:34:33
    2   NICK    WAHLBERG    2006-02-15 04:34:33
    3   ED  CHASE   2006-02-15 04:34:33
    4   JENNIFER    DAVIS   2006-02-15 04:34:33
    5   JOHNNY  LOLLOBRIGIDA    2006-02-15 04:34:33
```

This is how database table looked like when i see in `pgadmin2`:
[image]

I just want the `column_name` to return the column names of sql table as shown in **image**.

Comment: SQL queries are not ordered by default. If you want an order you need to impose it. In this case with `ORDER by ordinal_position`.

Comment: Another option is to use the [Cursor description](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html?highlight=description#cursor.description) to fetch the column names.